# C# Prevent DataGridView Leave

Tags: c#, datagridview, cells

```
    private void dgvWorkOrder_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == dgvWorkOrder.RowCount - 1)
        {
            try
            {
                string check = dgvWorkOrder.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input a valid entry.", "Empty");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 && e.RowIndex == dgvWorkOrder.RowCount - 1) ;
        {
            try
            {
                decimal check = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvWorkOrder.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
                if (check == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input a valid entry.");
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

With the code above, I'm trying to do a Leave Event that checks if the user inputted anything. If they didn't, I want it so that they can't leave that cell until they do, stopping anything else they can do aside from exiting the program entirely.

Updated as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a different event, [`CellValidating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvalidating%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and set `e.Cancel` to `true` if you want to keep the user from leaving the cell. You won't need to set the `CurrentCell` or `BeginEdit` using this event.

Comment: That works, however, it seems to lag behind by one step, I guess. I have another that checks if something is a decimal before allowing them to proceed. However, I can type in dog, and it will let me proceed the first time I leave the cell, but not the second.

Comment: @user3169698: post the code that's running in the event handler as an edit to your question.

Comment: @user3169698: so did you get it working? Or is there still something weird about the processing?

Comment: I did it as a Cell Value changed event, so it only did it when the value changed, and then later on in the processing, when the user clicks essentially a save button, it checks for blank entries and directs them to fix it first.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by others, the RowLeave event doesn't have an e.Cancel.  Try the RowValidating event which does have the e.Cancel available.  Got this from:
 "https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/440349-vb2005-stop-user-leaving-row-datagridview"

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Grid_Product_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    Grid_Product.EndEdit();   //it helps for instant value update before leaving.

    /// write youre code here...
}
```